# access movieclip inside a movieclip with dynamic name in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, dynamic, movieclip

:)

How can I access to seleral levels in a movieclip?

For example I have:

```
mc_base.mc_child_1.mc_child_child_1.visible = false;
```

So, can I access dynamically to this movieclips, I've tried with

```
mc_base.getChildByName("mc_child_" + 1).getChildByName("mc_child_child_" + 1).visible = false;
```

And also I've tried without success that:

```
var mc_base_and_child:DisplayObject = mc:base.getChildByName("mc_child" + 1); 
mc_base_and_child.getChildByName("mc_child_child_" + 1)
```

Any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mc_base["mc_child_"+1]["mc_child_child_"+1].visible = false;
```

try this one.